# Scala: Trait initialisation code using hard-coded values

Tags: scala, oop, inheritance, overriding, traits

The following code:

```
trait A{
  val s: String = "A"
  println(s"A's initialiser run, s= $s")
}

object O1 extends A {
  override val s = "O1"
  println(s"Object's initialiser run, s= $s")

  def foo: Unit = println("I am just being called to instantiate the object! :| ")
}

object O2 extends AnyRef with A {
  override val s = "O2"
  println(s"Object's initialiser run, s= $s")

  def foo: Unit = println("I am just being called to instantiate the object! :| ")
}

println("////with inheritance:")
O1.foo
println("////with mix-in:")
O2.foo
```

prints:

```
////with inheritance:
A's initialiser run, s= null
Object's initialiser run, s= O1
I am just being called to instantiate the object! :| 
////with mix-in:
A's initialiser run, s= null
Object's initialiser run, s= O2
I am just being called to instantiate the object! :|
```

I find the behaviour very strange. I would have expected one of the following behaviours :

- `"...s = O1"`, `"...s = O1"`
- `"...s = A "`, `"...s = O1"`

but neither happens.

I can understand a similar behaviour when `s` is left an abstract `val`, as opposed to a `def`, but I find it weird that the value is simply ignored. My questions are:

- What is happening under the surface that leads to this behaviour ?
- how similar/different does the compiler see the cases of running the initialisation block in a trait with hardcoded value vs a trait with abstract values.
- Why has Scala decided to do this as opposed to the two expected scenarios detailed above.
- Shouldn't the compiler warn us about having anything other than value setting in the body of traits?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is caused by `s` is **override** by the **subclass**, **Scala** `compiler` will translate it to the **abstract val**, like:

```
public abstract java.lang.String s();
```

the `s` will initialize after all `superclass` has finished initialization(`A`) and it will only initialize once(in `O1` or `O2`) after `superclass` finished initialization, so when `A`'s initialize block is trying to print `s` will get `null`.

and There is a reference is helpful:

https://docs.scala-lang.org/tutorials/FAQ/initialization-order.html